# Adicionar mais campos em form dinamicamente em Jquery

Tags: jquery, input

Estou criando um formulário, no qual o usuário irá adicionar mais campos dinamicamente. 
Peguei a função desse tutorial: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

O problema está ao adicionar, quero que cada campo venha com "Name" diferente.
tipo: "Texto1", "Texto2", "Texto3"...
como faço para aplicar essa função?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizando o exemplo que passou na pergunta, basta isso adicionar a seu `.append()`:

```
.append('<div><input type="text" name="Texto'
 +(+wrapper.find("input:text").length+1)
 '" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

No caso ele irá pegar a quantidade de inputs dentro da `div` que está na `var wrapper` e irá somar mais 1, já que já se possuí uma input dentro da `div`. Como você pode ver nesse exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var length = wrapper.find("input:text").length;

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="Texto' + (length+1) + '" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
    //Fazendo com que cada uma escreva seu name
    wrapper.find("input:text").each(function() {
      $(this).val($(this).attr('name'))
    });
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Desse modo há um detalhe, não chega a ser um problema, vai depender de você. Nele caso você delete a `input` de número 5. A outras continuarão com seus names. Então se deletou a 5, ordem agora é 1,2,3,4,6,7... Caso queira que sempre tenha a mesma ordem, você pode fazer da maneira abaixo:

Criei uma função `replaceName()`:

```
function replaceName(){
    wrapper.find("input:text").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', "Texto"+(+$(this).index("input:text")+1));                                 $(this).val($(this).attr('name'))
    });
}
```

Basta colocá-la para ser executada ao clicar em adicionar e ao remover:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();

    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
    //Fazendo com que cada uma escreva seu name
    replaceName();
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
    replaceName();
  })

  function replaceName() {
    wrapper.find("input:text").each(function() {
      $(this).attr('name', "Texto" + (+$(this).index("input:text") + 1));
      $(this).val($(this).attr('name'))
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

#### UpDate:

As inputs criados dinamicamente dei uma `class="textAdded"`, e agora a `var length` não conta todas as inputs e sim somente as com a class `textAdded`.

```
var length = wrapper.find("input:text").length;

$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" class="textAdded" name="Texto' + (length+1) + '" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

Veja aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/a4n0v8wf/1/

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu procurava. mt obrigado :)

Comment: Só uma observação. como meu formulário já tem 4 inputs, mesmo que como campos diferentes, ao adicionar ele já começa a contar do 5. como faço para resolver isso?

Comment: @LenoSousa, você deseja que comece do 1, independente de quantas existam?

Comment: Sim, pq meu formulário contem vários campos, nome, end. daí só quero que o campo fone, que sempre começa com um campo apenas.

Comment: @LenoSousa  Aconselho você a dar uma classe  a essas inputs que são criadas dinamicamente, assim fica bem mais fácil, irei editar a resposta com uma opção para isso

Comment: resposta  editada @LenoSousa

Answer (score 0):

Porque não usa o X para incluir um numeral a um nome:

```
var nome = 'Texto'+$x
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="$nome"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```