# Erro com o loop for

Tags: php

Queria que esse for exibisse um por um o conteúdo do meu formulário entretanto ele me exibe tudo de uma vez, o certo seria ele exibir o próximo só após de clicar em enviar e esse dados vou guardar em um array.

Seria minha logica que esta errada? alguém poderia me dar um auxilio.

Segue meu teste:

```
<?php
$totalPerguntas = 2;
$quantidadeVezes =0;

while($quantidadeVezes <= $totalPerguntas){
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPerguntas; $i++) {
        echo '<input type="text" name="produto[1][nome]" value="nome do produto" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="produto[1][valor]" value="valor do produto" />';
        echo '<input type="text" name="produto[1][codigo]" value="codigo do produto" />';
        echo '<button>Enviar</button>'; 
    }
    $quantidadeVezes++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Oi Fernando. Podes explicar melhor de que maneira o código que corre no browser deve "falar" com o PHP e gerar conteúdo? estás a usar ajax ou queres que isso aconteça quando a página carrega?

Comment: Oi Pablo, gostaria que só fosse exibido de um em um, e só exibi-se o próximo form após o click no botão, entretanto ele esta exibindo tudo de uma vez e só era para mostrar 2 formulários

Answer (score 0):

A forma que você desenvolveu o código realmente vai mostrar todas as informações de uma vez só, somente com php você não vai conseguir fazer isso, porque o php funciona assim, ele recebe uma requisição do servidor e o servidor responde com a pagina pronta (html, css, js) que foi montado pelo php.

Então o que esta acontecendo ai é o seguinte, você fez a requisição e ele retornou todas as informações de uma vez só, a melhor maneira de solucionar seu problema é, montar o formulário estático e colocar uma ação no botão para chamar um ajax, com o ajax você consegue pegar informações do php em background e jogar na tela, assim toda vez que você apertar o botão esta ação vai montar a tela "nova" para você.

Se você não tem ideia de como fazer, veja esta resposta: [Adicionar mais campos em form dinamicamente em Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108387/adicionar-mais-campos-em-form-dinamicamente-em-jquery)

Ela ensina como adicionar campos dinamicamente em um formulário.

**Update**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta foto vai te ajudar no seu problema.

Você vai montar um formulário inicial, nesta pagina você vai ter um jquery por exemplo, este jquery através do ajax vai chamar em background uma pagina php, esta pagina php vai manipular os dados, buscar as informações no banco e depois de tudo pronto construir um json, este json vai ser enviado novamente para o jquery, e por fim o jquery vai construir os novos campos na tela, então você vai ter que estudar sobre:

- jquery (Ele vai manipular a tela)
- ajax (Ele vai realizar as ações com o php em background)
- json (Esta e a linguagem que você vai utilizar para trocar mensagem com o js)
- php (acredito que você já saiba como funciona)

Comment: Entendi o script que eu estava tentando fazer algo igual só que com alterações em php estava em JS puro, pelo que eu pesquisei com esse link e outras paginas eu não vou conseguir enviar o que receber do jquery para o php eu teria que ter um intermediário que serio o json correto? ou tem outra forma?

Comment: Json é uma ótima alternativa!

Comment: Único problema é que nunca utilizei json, ele é um arquivo que pode ser acessado diretamente pelo brownser ou não é que nem o php fica oculto? usando ele posso acessar tanto com js ou php correto?

Comment: É complicado explicar aqui, mas vou te dar um norte, é uma string, onde você pode trocar informações entre o javascript e o php, para você entender melhor veja este link: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: Editei a pergunta para te ajudar no seu problema, mas em resumo você vai ter que estudar algumas coisas para poder fazer o que você quer. @Fernando